# SwiftUI - inline hyperlink

Tags: swiftui, hyperlink, interpolation

I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image]

Originally I implemented as follows:

```
Text("[Call the store direct](tel://09928282828) or check our [FAQs section](https://faq-url.co.uk/terms-and-conditions) for more details")
```

This gives me the desired outcome:

[image]

However, I need to pick the phone number up from a viewModel I have connected to this view. But as soon as I try to interpolate it, the functionality no longer works.

So, in the viewModel I had:

```
let number = "09928282828" // This would actually need to be dynamically taken from a `store` object, but this just for testing purposes
```

But when I then use this as follows:

```
Text("[Call the store direct](tel://\(viewModel.number)) or check our [FAQs section](https://faq-url.co.uk/terms-and-conditions) for more details")
```

There is no hyperlink.

[image]

Wondering why I can't use this value and inject it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue last week. I couldn't find the exact problem, but somehow it works if you use another init method like the following:

```swift
Text(.init("[Call the store direct](tel://\(viewModel.number)) or check our [FAQs section](https://faq-url.co.uk/terms-and-conditions) for more details"))
```

But for this kind of reasons I always prefer `AttributedString`.

```swift
struct ViewModel {
    let number: String = "09928282828"

    var attributedString: AttributedString {
        return try! AttributedString(
            markdown: "[Call the store direct](tel://\(number)) or check our [FAQs section](https://faq-url.co.uk/terms-and-conditions) for more details"
        )
    }
}

Text(viewModel.attributedString) // <-- Usage
```